# How can I find the second smallest output for my function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, format

I used this function to find the biggest pullback $ wise for my data frame column with stock prices. I need help to figure out how to get the X following output. Basically the plan is to join those outputs into a new data frame to get the X biggest pullbacks within my data frame.

**Main question:**
How could I loop through the X biggest pullback, starting at the biggest pullback and finding the X next biggest pullback?

```
def maxdrop(p):
bestdrop = 0
wheredrop = -1,-1
i = 0
while i < len(p) - 1:
    if p[i+1] < p[i]:
        bestlocal = p[i+1]
        wherelocal = i+1
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(p) - 1 and p[j + 1] < p[i]:
            j += 1
            if p[j] < bestlocal:
                bestlocal = p[j]
                wherelocal = j
        if p[i] - bestlocal > bestdrop:
            bestdrop = p[i] - bestlocal
            wheredrop = i, wherelocal
        i = j+1
    else:
        i += 1
return bestdrop,wheredrop
```

maxdrop(df1['price'])

Here is the current output for the code:

```
(782.5300000000001, (1640, 1657))
```

Comment: Could you share the sample input data as well?

Answer (score 1):

The strategy u can use is to first find the biggest pullback, then exclude that range where that pullback is and then calculate the biggest pullback for all valid ranges that are left.

I made my own `maxdrop` function that works in a similar fashion as yours, except it only looks within specified bounds. Then `alldrops` returns an array of all draw-downs without overlap. Then you could sort this array by the $ draw-down to get what you want.

```
def maxdrop(pricearray, leftbound=0 , rightbound=-1):
    # Calculate the pullback/drop by splitting the array in half,
    # then calculating the max of the first and the min of the second.
    # By testing all "splitting points" and selecting the maximum we get the biggest drop
    drops = []
    begin, end = -1, -1
    if rightbound == -1:
        rightbound = len(pricearray)
    for i in range(leftbound+1,rightbound-1):
        leftpart = pricearray[leftbound:i]
        rightpart = pricearray[i:rightbound]
        
        begin = pricearray.index(max(leftpart))
        end = pricearray.index(min(rightpart))
        delta = max(leftpart)-min(rightpart)
        drops.append([delta, begin, end])
    if len(drops) > 0:
        return max(drops)
    else:
        return None;



def alldrops(pricearray):
    droplist = [] # Stores all the drops

    droplist.append(maxdrop(pricearray))

    while True:
        termswhereadded = False
        validranges = [] # Stores all ranges that are not part of drawdown

        #Get ranges that are not already part of a drawdown
        for i in range(-1, len(droplist)):
            if(i == -1):
                b = 0
            else:
                b = droplist[i][2]
            
            if(i == len(droplist)-1):
                e = len(pricearray)-1
            else:
                e = droplist[i+1][1]
            
            if (b < e-1):
                validranges.append((b, e));
        
        # If there are no valid ranges left, we are finished
        if (len(validranges) == 0):
            break;

        #Calculate the biggest drawdown in all those valid ranges
        for vrange in validranges:
            drop = maxdrop(pricearray, vrange[0], vrange[1])
            if (drop != None):
                if (drop[0] > 0):
                    droplist.append(drop)
                    termswhereadded = True
        
        droplist.sort(key= lambda n : n[1])

        # If no drawdown was added we are finished
        if(not termswhereadded):
            break;
    
    return droplist
```

For a array with a hundred random elements you get (the first element in each array is the pullback, the second where it starts, the third where it ends)

> [[0.6391820462436719, 0, 1], [4.945067107442718, 3, 7], [0.38440828483857103, 10, 11], [0.44438096165870533, 14, 15], [1.2783529599412589, 23, 24], [0.20126563551455945, 25, 26], [1.1957951552365884, 28, 30], [0.5895546638677374, 32, 37], [1.5337809447945148, 40, 41], [3.0108867730327518, 43, 60], [1.0752516082881058, 67, 68], [1.0413928565593054, 70, 71], [3.039113846862932, 82, 87], [6.364453213541438, 92, 99]]

Which when you plot the pullbacks in matplotlib:
[image: plotting in matplotlib]

Comment: Hey there, thank you for the help.
what would would the data frame you are using look like and how would you run the function itself accordingly if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: I'm not using a dataframe here just a simple array, don't really know how dataframes work. To use the function I just used `d = alldrops(stock_prices)` where stock_prices is a array generated by a random walk.